# How to install NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to install npm.I tries directly to install npm through command prompt without downloads anything as shown below:

```
[root@localhost app]# npm install -g meteorite
bash: npm: command not found
[root@localhost app]#
```

I am using the above scenario to install npm but gets error as shown below :

ERROR is :

```
bash: npm: command not found
```

I am new to meteor.So I didn't get any idea about installation of npm.I am raise a query as below :

NPM installation through command prompt or download or download and command prompt?

Can you please suggest me what to do for NPM installatiom?

Comment: `I need to install npm` and `npm: command not found`: infinite loop detected. Install [node](http://nodejs.org/) to get npm. `npm` is the node package manager. You cannot use it until you have it somewhere on your system.

Comment: Yes,But here node page install option there.Click install option then download file.then what i can do.Can you please explain to me?.@ Simon

Comment: Did you get Node from the project site? The official binaries for Linux contain a `/bin` folder with exactly 2 files: `node` and `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

As commentators stated, You have to install node first to get access to npm package manager.

Its hard to give straight answer, as You didnt tell us what OS You're running.

You can compile it (recommended), or use packages with pre-built binaries, for ie.

Here is general answer:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation

and for installing without compilation:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation#installing-without-building

here is ubuntu installation from soruces example:

http://shapeshed.com/compiling-nodejs-from-source-on-ubuntu-10-04/

PS google gives hundreds of answer for this question...